# Shell script: how can make the line present vertically with one line command?

Tags: shell, sh

my input:

```
ads bdsd cds dds
ac  cv ss    ds

dsd
```

output I expect:

```
ads
bdsd
cds
dds
ac
cv
ss
ds
dsd
```

command I used:

```
cat file1.txt | perl -p -i -e 's/\n(.+)/$1/'
```

but it does not work

Comment: Perl is decidedly overkill here. The basic problem is that `.+` matches the entire line, including whitespace. You probably meant something like `s/\n?(\S+)\s+/$1\n/g`

Comment: Also, the `-i` option makes no sense when the data comes from standard input.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cat file1.txt | tr -s " " "\n"
```

Basically, it replaces spaces with newlines and removes empty lines.

Comment: That's a [useless `cat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat); you want `tr " " "\n" < file1.txt`

Comment: You can squeeze the whitespace with `-s`: `tr -s ' ' \\n` will do it all.